# how to make a link click to stay on same page

Tags: javascript, href

I have the following code:

```
<area href="/?22" shape="poly" coords="438,388,561,211">
<area href="/?23" shape="poly" coords="338,43,61,21">
```

when it's clicked the link send the "signal" and working fine, but the page change to:

```
http://192.168.0.177/?22
```

or

```
http://192.168.0.177/?23
```

and I want to keep the page to:

```
http://192.168.0.177
```

it's there a way/hack to click the link to send the signal but the page remain and of course to not refresh?

Thank you so much!

Comment: inline try: `onclick="return false"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: usually href's ar used to transfer the request to another page.. If you want to redirect another page still the existing page remain open use target attribute.. If you dont want to redirect anywhere and still want send a signal while clicking the text, use onclick on the text and not the href.

Comment: it;s there a way to put a "fake" area on top to call the http://x.x.x.x/?22 but themain page to not change?

Comment: could you use fragment? eg: /#/22

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have no need for the href, return false onclick or use a JavaScript href:

```
<area href="/?22" onclick="return false" shape="poly" coords="438,388,561,211">

<area href="javascript:void(0)" shape="poly" coords="338,43,61,21">
```

If you DO need to load the href, use Ajax or add a named iframe and target it:

```
<area href="/?22" target="Iframe" shape="poly" coords="438,388,561,211">

...

<iframe name="Iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: i need to click on the http://192.168.0.177/?22 to do the job but in same time the webpage to remain at http://192.168.0.177. Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you try second example?

Comment: I don't know how, because I need to call /?22 and if I put href="javascript:void(0)" how to put href="/?22"  ?

Comment: no ajax. I need to call /?22 ,/?23 etc with link, button or area but the link in the status bar to remain the same. and not to add the  /?22 at the end, but the request to be sent. Like If i put in web browser http://192.168.0.123/?22 it sends the "impulse" but I want the page that was requested from to remain the same without /?22 at the end because there is nothing, it's just a call

Comment: Then you need to target a hidden frame. You cannot make an HTTP request without making an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding onclick attribute as follows.

```
<area href="/?23" shape="poly" coords="338,43,61,21" onclick="return false;">
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Vetrivel but unfortunately after click on the link the address in the bar will change to http://192.168.0.177/?22  and of course nothing is there...

Comment: I tried it on an <a> tag. It prevented click and also browser URL remained unchanged. Not sure what would be the case with <area> tag.